# Анонимные боксы и прозрачные элементы в HTML 5

Tags: html5

[image: Блоки в шапке сайта]

**В приведённом примере задача:** в шапке сайта (header) сделать 2 блока (1-й группирует название и слоган; 2-ой включает просто отдельную ссылку на что-либо). Сделать эти блоки ссылками, использовать минимум элементов HTML 5.

Правильно будет на скриншоте? Header - секция, блочный. В нём "a" строчный, оборачивает 2 параграфа. Отдельная ссылка заключена в блочный элемент "p".

Поскольку в блочном элементе не могут быть одновременно строчные и блочные элементы, то в виду того, что "p" блочный, "а" будет автоматически обёрнут в анонимный блок, который и будет группировать название и слоган.

Я правильно выполнил данную задачу или название и слоган стоит обернуть в дополнительный div?

Comment: а кто тебя учил в строчный элемент блочный засовывать?

Comment: Спецификация HTML 5

Comment: перечитай)))  блочные в строчные, не то что нельзя, а запрещено

Comment: Есть несколько элементов, которые являются прозрачными, в том числе и "a". Если в родителе "а" разрешены блочные элементы, то и "а" наследует от него это свойство.

Comment: нет, не все....